# Set height based on fixed siblings

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have some code that works almost perfectly. I have the following requirements:

- A banner with the same text fixed to the top and bottom of the viewport.
- `childContent` should scroll when the contents overflow beyond the available space without moving the banners
- The scroll bar is positioned within `#contentContainer`, not the entire viewport.
- The `#window-container` div should be able to live in any size div in the viewport. It will not always fill the screen.

If you were to change the `numberOfParagraphs` and your viewport as it is now, this works perfectly.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYVNbd

However, the banner text is going to be a variable length. Using `calc(100% - 3em)` doesn't work when there is more than one row of text because the height of the two banners is now `6em`. You can see this by un-commenting line 7 of the JS. The bottom banner is now pushed off the screen.

---

How do I keep the bottom banner from being pushed off the screen when there is more than 1 line of text in the banners?

I have searched far and wide, and `calc(100% - 3em)` is the answer I keep coming back to.

If at all possible, I'd like to figure out a pure HTML/CSS solution and not include js/jquery.

---

### Final Solution

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZxrmg

This is mostly [kukkuz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689993/10559113) using the flexbox. I also added a relative font size to the banners so it wouldn't overtake the content when the overall size is much smaller.

You can play around with the number of paragraphs and verify the banner stays at the bottom of the viewport. Also, horizontal scroll works perfectly too. (uncomment line 23).

Comment: I guess you have to decide a fixed size for the top and bottom banners, then this is a easy solve, other than that some content of the scroll able area may hidden by the footer banner, since we have to use `position:fixed` property with the footer banner to maintain it's position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *flexbox* layout here:

1. Make your `window-container` a *column* `flexbox` with *viewport height* (you can remove the `calc` height set on `contentContainer` and add `flex: 1`)
2. Also set `margin: 0` to the `body` element to *reset* the default margin and preventing *margin collapsing* with the margin of the `p` elements inside.

See demo below:

```js
var bannerText = "Demo Application";
var numberOfParagraphs = 8;
/**
 * Change the length of the banner so it runs to the second line
 * You might need to adjust your screen width
 */
bannerText = "Fixed Alert with super long footer that will eventually run off the screen and onto the next line. If we don't handle this, the footer will get pushed off the screen";

var banners = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-text");
for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
  banners[i].innerHTML = bannerText;
}

// This just generates an amount of paragraphs to test the vertical resizing
var text =
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

var returnArray = ["<p>" + text + "</p>"];
/**
 * Check how horizontal scrolling looks
 * The content moves, but the banners stay fixed
 */
// returnArray = ['<p style="width: 200%">' + text + '</p>']

for (var i = 1; i < numberOfParagraphs; i++) {
  returnArray.push("<p>" + text + "</p>");
}
document.getElementById("childContent").innerHTML = returnArray;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* ADDED */
}

.window-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh; /* ADDED */
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  flex-direction: column; /* ADDED */
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar-text {
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#contentContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1; /* ADDED */
  /*height: calc(100% - 3em);*/
  /* For non-scrolling content */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#childContent {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="window-container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="bar-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="contentContainer">
      <div id="childContent">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="bar-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is almost there. When the content doesn't fill the entire screen, the banner should still be at the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: @Nathan add `flex: 1` to the `#contentContainer`, see edited answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using `position:sticky` to both header and footer of your code.

*Javascript code isn't necessary I just used it to create a dynamic header & footer.*

You can find the updated pen [here](https://codepen.io/yourpalnurav/pen/bzxgvx).

```js
var paraNum = 15;
var content =
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

function repeat(paraNum, content) {
  for (i = 0; i < paraNum; i++) {
    paraCount = i + 1;
    document.getElementById("contentContainer").innerHTML =
      document.getElementById("contentContainer").innerHTML +
      "<p>" +
      paraCount +
      ") " +
      content +
      "</p>";
  }
}
repeat(paraNum, content);


function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, html) {
  var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
  var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
  newElement.setAttribute("id", elementId);
  newElement.innerHTML = html;
  p.appendChild(newElement);
}
function removeElement(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #222;
  height: 85vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.windowContainer {
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3);
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#contentContainer {
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#contentHeader {
  text-align: center;
  color: #222222;
  background: #dddddd;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
#contentFooter {
  text-align: center;
  color: #222222;
  background: #dddddd;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addElement('contentHeader', 'div', 'fixedHeadingLine','Header Line');" value="Add a Header Line" />
<input type="button" onclick="removeElement('fixedHeadingLine');" value="Remove a Header Line" />
<div class="windowContainer">
  <div id="contentHeader">Header Line</div>
  <div id="contentContainer">
    Content Heading
  </div>
  <div id="contentFooter">Footer Line</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addElement('contentFooter', 'div', 'fixedFooterLine','Footer Line');" value="Add a Footer Line" />
<input type="button" onclick="removeElement('fixedFooterLine');" value="Remove a Footer Line" />
```

> Please do note that removing the original Header/Footer using the
>   buttons throws an error.

I hope you find this helpful.

Peace

Comment: This is almost there. When the content doesn't fill the entire screen, the banner should still be at the bottom of the viewport. Set number of paragraphs to 2 to reproduce.